# How do I hide and check the attribute of another element for each li in an unordered list during a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay - I am trying to reverse loop through the `<li>` contained in an unordered list. During this loop I want to remove each `<li>` and then compare the height of it's parent column to that of an adjacent column until it is =< the other. Once this is true break the loop and display remaining `<li>`. Before this happens I am using shuffle.js to shuffle the list. I have been able to capture the height of both columns but my code seems to be messed up once I start looping through the `<li>`

Here is the HTML short version...

```
<body>  
  <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header"></div>
             <div id="main">This is the column that would set the height that determines the amount of [li] shown
            </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul id="shuffleunorderedlist">
                <li id="promo_1">
                    1
                </li>
                <li id="promo_2">
                    2
                </li>
                <li id="promo_3">
                    3
                </li>
                <li id="promo_4">
                    4
                </li>
                <li id="promo_5">
                    5
                </li>
                <li id="promo_6">
                    6
                </li>
                <li id="promo_7">
                    7
                </li>
                <li id="promo_8">
                    8
                </li>
                <li id="promo_9">
                    9
                </li>
                <li id="promo_10">
                    10
                </li>
                <li id="promo_11">
                    11
                </li>
                <li id="promo_12">
                    12
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

And here is the jQuery and Javascript I have written so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($)
{
    window.onload = function()
    { 
        $('#shuffleunorderedlist').shuffle();   //********** Shuffle List 
    };
    var mainHeight = $('#main').height();   //********** Capture 'main' height 
    var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').height();     //********** Capture 'sidebar'     height 
        if (mainHeight > sidebarHeight)     //********** Compare 'sidebar' height 
            {
                var liCheck = $('div#sidebar.li').reverse().each(function ()    //********** reverse Loop through <li>'s  
                    {
                    while(liCheck())
                        {
                           $('li').hide(); //********** reverse Loop through <li>'s 
                             if (sidebarHeight =< mainHeight) 
                                    {
                                    break;  // breaks loop completely   //**********  Output <li>'s that are left 
                                    }
                        }  
                    }   
            }               
});
</script>
```

So basically why isn't this working? Where am I breaking it? How can I get it to work?

Any suggestions, Help and answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can put this code into a JS fiddle, kind of hard to see it immediately right here. Also, there are functions like `liCheck()` which we can't even see what they are doing

Comment: Also, `$('li').hide()` is going to hide every list item on the page.

Comment: One more thing: I'm not seeing any updates to `mainHeight` so it will always be the initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was riddled with problems, so instead of detailing them all, compare your code to this:

```
var mainHeight = $('#main').height();
var sidebarHeight = $('#sidebar').height();
if (mainHeight < sidebarHeight) { // You are hiding things from the sidebar correct? Strictly speaking, this check isn't necessary, but it prevents us from looping when we don't need to. 
    $('div#sidebar li').each(function() {  // I removed reverse as it gave me a reference error. If it is defined for you, feel free to use it. 
        if (sidebarHeight > mainHeight) {  
            $(this).hide();  // hide only the current element
            sidebarHeight = $("#sidebar").height(); // update sidebarHeight 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok- obviously I need to go back and redo all of this. Thanks for the suggestions.